# React container scope is not inherited by component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, components, containers

I've seperated container and component and now facing the issues with rerendering component.

```
render() {
    return <DomainEdit schema={this.props.schema} domain={this.domain} formData={this.props.formData} updateSubType={this.updateSubType} types={this.props.types}/>;
}
```

I am sending `updateSubType` method which is a callback method whenever anything in the form is changed.

After its changed I am sending back what is changed and I have to update this.props.schema in order to re-render the component with the new schema.

The problem I am facing is that the callback methods `this` is the scope of the component and not container itself, in other words component only has the arguments I've sent in the render method, which is a problem because I can't access the container props and re-render the component.

How could I re-render the component in the callback method which is defined in the container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a context binding issue.

If you want updateSubType to be called inside DomainEdit and still have `this` inside this callback pointing to the container reference, you have to bind updateSubType to the container instance.

Two ways are available to do this:
In the constructor of the container, redefine `this.updateSubType = this.updateSubType.bind(this);`

Or if you're using ES6, define updateSubType this way:

```
updateSubType = () => {
    ...method definition
}
```

The arrow function notation (`() => {}`) auto binds the function to the surrounding instance.